# How to Save Data in RadGridView on Window Closed WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, telerik, radgridview, savechanges

I am currently using Telerik's RadGridView to display data from a database.  I also have empty columns for users to enter in any extra information.  What I want the application to do is once I close the window to the gridview, the information that the user has entered into the grid will be saved, and when I open the application again the information will load accordingly and will still be there.  Is there a way of doing this?  I've searched many different threads and forums and haven't found a clear solution.  The main trend that I've seen is saving this information back to a database, but I would like to avoid doing that if possible.  I've attempted Telerik's suggestion of using their PersistanceFramework tool, but to no avail.  If anyone is able to help me with this, it would be most appreciated.
**EDIT:**
I should also mention that I am displaying the data from the database using a linq query, which is the reason why the PersistanceFramework tool doesn't really work for my situation.
Here is the linq query in my `Window_Loaded`event.  The Deduction_ID, Check_No, and Check_Date are the empty three columns that users will be entering in information into.  Basically, I want to save any information the user inputs into those columns when they close the window so that it is still there when they open it:

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Loads queries from each of the designated data tables in BSI_Test
        var customerQuery =
            (from customer in testEntity.Customers
             join job in testEntity.Jobs
             on customer.CID equals job.CID
             join claim in testEntity.Claims
             on job.JID equals claim.JID
             select new DataProperties
             {
                 Customer_Name = customer.CName,
                 Customer_ID = customer.CID,
                 Job_ID = job.JID,
                 Claim_ID = claim.CLAIMID,
                 Deduction_ID = DeductId,
                 Check_No = CheckNo,
                 Check_Date = CheckDate
             })
            .OrderBy(c => c.Customer_Name);

        //Populates the Telerik data grid with data.
        gridView.ItemsSource = customerQuery.ToList();
    }
```

I am mostly confused as to what I put into the `Window_Closing` event to save that information, and what I put into `Window_Loaded` to load the information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is Possible in Radcontrols.But it depend in which version you Using.if you Using demo version probably they might not Offer that.if you Using Licence version they do have it for sure.

The way to do is in close event you have to save data in database (or text file if you don't want to save data in database).make sure you run a Update command to under close event and once you load data back you have to load data in loading event , to particular column.in your code i don't see you loading data from where you save the data in under close event.

Hope this will help you to solve your problem.

Comment: So, I should save the data back to the database that I am pulling the information from is what you're saying?  What about the columns that do not have a database associated with them? Those are the custom made columns that I have created for this application where users will be inputting in their own information.

Comment: Yes.for your first question. Make another extra column in database and check when you loading data with other columns to grid.if that extra column is empty display it empty or skip loading that.if you have data just display data as you do with other columns.and when you close the window check user enter any data in new columns and make a update command and update database colum.

Comment: Gotcha.  Turns out my application will be taking a slightly different direction, so this question is pretty much irrelevant at the moment.  Thank you for the response though, as it was helpful!